# Truffle develop (Ganache) increase block gas limit

Tags: solidity, truffle

I can deploy my contract on Remix (Javascript VM and Rinkeby), but if I try to use `truffle develop` and `migrate`, I am getting an error: `Error: Exceeds block gas limit`. The gas used in Remix is 3585084.

How can I make it work in truffle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try manually setting the gas limit in your truffle.js file for your development network:

```
development : {
 ...
 gas: 4612388
}
```

Comment: This works, but there is still another limit that seems hardcoded around 6700000 gas.

Comment: As of Jan 2019, the hardcoded gas limit in `ganache-cli` is 6721975.

Comment: `which truffle`
`code /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/truffle`
crtl+f 6721975

Comment: Works well, BUT... is user runs truffle develop, then network name must be develop (not development)

Answer (score 5):

The gas parameter in truffle.js is NOT the chain's block gas limit. It means maximum to pay for deploys.

So doesn't matter how big you set the number as long as a actual gas required is larger than the hardcoded chain block gas limit you will get the same error again and again!

Here's my answer:

[Truffle contract deployment either exceeds block gas limit or out of gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59485/truffle-contract-deployment-either-exceeds-block-gas-limit-or-out-of-gas/59486#59486)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can check your maximum gas limit with `web3.eth.getBlock("pending").gasLimit` command in `truffle develop` console.

Example:

```
truffle(develop)> web3.eth.getBlock("pending").gasLimit
6721975
```

That is the maximum number you can set in `truffle.js`

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      gas: "6721975",
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

Source: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/271#issuecomment-341952559

Answer (score 1):

I solved it and now can run mocha ganache tests without truffle. [Solidity Exceeds block gas limit during Mocha Tests with Ganache-cli](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46957/solidity-exceeds-block-gas-limit-during-mocha-tests-with-ganache-cli)