# Solidity Exceeds block gas limit during Mocha Tests with Ganache-cli

Tags: solidity, gas-limit, ganache, mocha

How can I increase the gas limit in this case? The error message is "n: Exceeds block gas limit" or "base fee exceeds gas limit".

I think there is some kind of api I need to set the block gas limit [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html).

Are my contracts too large? Should I test each contract one by one instead?
Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: exceeds block gas limit ganache

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message

> "n: Exceeds block gas limit"

means your transaction has declared a gas value greater that the maximum allowed in the network. A client will reject such transaction.

With ganache-cli you can launch with a larger amount of gas available with the `-l` parameter:

```
ganache-cli -l 8000000
```

Will launch ganache with a block gas limit of 8M.

---

From the [readme documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#library) it has a mode where you pass extra options in a parameter when you launch ganache. There you can set `gasLimit`.

```
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const options = { gasLimit: 8000000 };
const server = ganache.server(options);
server.listen(port, (err, blockchain) => {
    /* */
});
```

Comment: Hi Ismael, how can I add this command inside my Javascript file so I can run this file during Mocha Tests with Ganache-cli ? Thanks

Comment: @user2965665 How do you start your ganache instance? You can pass more options in the extra parameter, you can set `gasLimit` from there.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out: const provider = ganache.provider(options);

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Ismael's solution:

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const options = { gasLimit: 8000000 };
const provider = ganache.provider(options);
// quote from doc "Both .provider() and .server() take a single object
// which allows you to specify behavior of ganache-cli"
// https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#using-ganache-cli
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```