# Ganache: out-of-gas during deployment

Tags: truffle, ganache, out-of-gas

I have a bunch of [contracts](https://github.com/crossbario/xbr-protocol/tree/master/contracts) which deploy [just fine](https://travis-ci.org/crossbario/xbr-protocol/builds/645407760).

Deployment of one of the contracts, `XBRNetwork` takes exactly 5418911 gas - no problems with that.

However, once I [add another trivial (public) function](https://github.com/crossbario/xbr-protocol/pull/68) to the contract, deployment during CI run for the PR [fails](https://travis-ci.org/crossbario/xbr-protocol/builds/645439899):

```
   Replacing 'XBRNetwork'
   ----------------------

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"XBRNetwork" ran out of gas (using a value you set in your network config or deployment parameters.)
   * Block limit:  0x989680
   * Gas sent:     10000000

    at /home/oberstet/scm/crossbario/xbr-protocol/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:364:1
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Truffle v5.1.11 (core: 5.1.11)
Node v10.16.0
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'deploy' failed
make: *** [deploy] Error 1
```

I have set:

- [`--gasLimit=10000000`](https://github.com/crossbario/xbr-protocol/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L29) in ganache command options
- [`gas=10000000`](https://github.com/crossbario/xbr-protocol/blob/71a44c1af274b889f7c06a522d703ee2b99f4483/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js#L34) in migrations

**What other option do I need? How would I change the [PR](https://github.com/crossbario/xbr-protocol/pull/68) to get rid of the "out of gas" issue?**

---

Do test, start ganache:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate ganache
```

and deploy

```
truffle migrate --reset --network ganache
```

---

**UPDATE (solution)**

The real reason (see the answer) is: apparently, there is a 24kB size restriction on the deployed bytecode (besides the gas limits).

I have added this helper to our CI:

https://github.com/crossbario/xbr-protocol/blob/6f7384c51d52c4d88bfa88314841baf63fc0b7cf/check-abi-files.py

Result:

```
WORKS:

(cpy381_3) oberstet@intel-nuci7:~/scm/crossbario/xbr-protocol$ python check-abi-files.py 
..
ABI file "abi/XBRNetwork.json           " bytecode= 25547  bytes, deployedBytecode= 23998  bytes 
..

FAILS:

(cpy381_3) oberstet@intel-nuci7:~/scm/crossbario/xbr-protocol$ python check-abi-files.py 
..
ABI file "abi/XBRNetwork.json           " bytecode= 26344  bytes, deployedBytecode= 24795  bytes   WARNING - maximum deployed contract size of 24kB exceeded
..
```

And the actual solution consequently: [refactoring](https://github.com/crossbario/xbr-protocol/pull/69) the contract code into a library. Can be done  .. np .. now that I know this hidden limit;)

Comment: where are you deploying to?  If it's your own private network it will have it's own maximum gas per block, which you could be exceeding?

Comment: this might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46957/solidity-exceeds-block-gas-limit-during-mocha-tests-with-ganache-cli

Comment: Check the size of the byte-code (bin file). If the byte-code is larger than 24KB (the bin file larger than 48KB) after you add that function, then it would explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of checking the size of your contract's byte-code in your [GitHub repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crossbario/xbr-protocol/master/abi/XBRNetwork.json).

It turns out to be 51708 hexadecimal characters, which means ‭25854‬ bytes when deployed.

Ethereum has a contract code-size limit of 24KB, i.e., ‭24576‬ bytes.

If you contract's code-size exceeds this limit, then your contract deployment will fail.

Comment: yes, that was exactly the problem! I'll update the question with what I did exactly. anyways: thanks so much! =) I don't think I would have been able to find this _actual_ reason: the "out of gas error" is .. misleading at best if you don't happen to know this 24kB bytecode size restrictions. I wasn't aware, and wasted like 10+ hours on this. well. thanks again!

Comment: @oberstet: You're welcome. I think I must have spent 4-5 hours myself when I first encountered that problem. And you're right, the "out of gas error" is misleading. I'm actually quite sure that I've mentioned this fact when I answered here a question similar to yours a while ago.