# Truffle contract deployment either exceeds block gas limit or out of gas

Tags: truffle, remix, gas-limit, out-of-gas

I've been having the same issue when I was trying to deploy a contract using truffle develop console. The contract is not extremely big but does initiate two other contracts when called a certain function. (since it's not open to the public so apologies i can't post the contract here)

I came across the error "**out of gas**" when I didn't specify the gas used in my **2_deploy_contract.js** file, but when I gradually increased the the gas at some point I got the error "**Exceeds block gas limit**".

I then tried to specify the "gas" parameter in **truffle.js** config file. **The problem is no matter how high I set it (e.g. 10000000000000) it still gave me the same error: "Exceeds block gas limit"**.

```
 networks: {
  development: {
   host: "127.0.0.1",
   from: "0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57",
   port: 9545,
   network_id: "*", // Match any network id
   gas: 18900000000000000000000000000
}
```

}

**And the most interesting part of it is that  it worked perfectly fine on Remix but not truffle develop console.**

Answer (score 2):

**Answer(I found out the answer by myself)**:

The gas parameter in truffle.js is the maximum amount you are willing to pay for deploys. It is **not** **the chain's block gas limit!** So doesn't matter how big that is, if the block gas limit is smaller than the gas you attach to a transaction, you will always get the same error "Exceeds block gas limit". Which also explains why it worked in Remix not on my local chain.

Now the question is how do I change the default block gas limit for the truffle develop local chain? I don't see the genesis.json file. The hardcoded block gas limit seems to be around 6700000.

I assume the solutions are below:
1. change the hardcoded truffle core setting to allow higher block gas limit.
2. break down the contract to make it lighter.
3. connect truffle to a local network you set up yourself or to the live testnet, which may or may not allow the gas required by the contract. So always test first using the mainnet gas requirements.

Any further help is much appreciated!

Comment: in both ganache (settings-> chain) and  
ganache-cli - [link to other article](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46957/solidity-exceeds-block-gas-limit-during-mocha-tests-with-ganache-cli)  
  
you can set the gas limit.

Comment: @shaddow. Thank you. That link goes to my post. I just solved it in mocha ganache testing without truffle. See the post :)

Comment: If you have more doubts it is better to create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

What most mix is development and develop. When you set params in truffle.js for **development** you are setting for **truffle console**, when you set it for **develop** you are setting it for **truffle develop**

so you should add this to your truffle.js and blocklimit will be fine.

develop: {
host: "localhost",
port: 7546,
gas: 50000000,
gasLimit: 8000000,
network_id: "*", // Match any network id
},